# I want to call a function when state changes

Tags: reactjs, function, state, ecmascript-5, setstate

When we call `setstate({})` after it, it has to call function My requirements. I want to add or remove classes on specific state so I want to check state in runtime and call a function on a specific state.

Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem "i want to add or remove classes on specific state " you could access component state inside `render` method to implement the requirement. Also `setState` allows the second argument, callback beeing called when the state is updated.

Comment: You can do `this.setState({ ... }, myFunction)` and `myFunction` will be called after the state has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do this :

```
this.setState({ state }, () => {
          //do stuff
        });
```